# PowerShell Get-ChildItem how to catch Exception

Tags: powershell, exception, try-catch

Im currently programming a visual error GUI that catches any exception while processing and give's the user an "easy to understand" error message. But it seems that I can't catch any exceptions while using the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet. Do I have to use a different method than try / catch?

Here's the PowerShell script:

```
if ($checkBox1.Checked)    {
    Try{
        Get-ChildItem -path K:\adm_spm_logdb_data\ADP\DATA |Rename-Item -newname { $($_.BaseName -split '_provide')[0] + $_.Extension };
        }catch [System.Exception]{
        $listBox1.Items.Add("An error occured while trying to process ADP-Files please check the manual!")
        }
        $listBox1.Items.Add("Please check your System files to ensure the process has finished")
    }
```

I tried to create an exception by using a false `-path` which results in a `DriveNotFoundException`. But it looks like I can't catch it by using try / catch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `-ErrorAction Stop` to the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet:

```
if ($checkBox1.Checked)    {
    Try{
        Get-ChildItem -path "K:\adm_spm_logdb_data\ADP\DATA" -ErrorAction Stop |Rename-Item -newname { $($_.BaseName -split '_provide')[0] + $_.Extension };
        }catch [System.Exception]{
        $listBox1.Items.Add("An error occured while trying to process ADP-Files please check the manual!")
        }
        $listBox1.Items.Add("Please check your System files to ensure the process has finished")
    }
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! I will accept this answer as soon as i can.