# PowerShell fails when trying to read certificate store with "The specified network resource or device is no longer available"

Tags: powershell, certificate, certificate-store

I was trying to find a specific certificate on my machine, and I ran into an odd issue. I was seeing `The specified network resource or device is no longer available` errors when calling:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "XXXXX" -Recurse
```

Where `"XXXX"` was the thumbprint of the certificate I was looking for.

To try to narrow down the issue, I started by removing the thumbprint of my command (i.e. calling `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`), and found that the script failed when trying to read from the `UserDS` certificate store (see abbreviated screenshot of output, below):

[image: <code>Get-ChildItem -Recurse</code> output]

I then tried to `cd` into the `UserDS` certificate store to see if it would even let me, and to see if I could see anything in that location. Upon trying to call `ls` I received the same error (see below):

[image]

I can't figure out what's causing this issue or how to fix it. It's blocking me on the local installation of a client's solution, so any help or ideas are very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the registry key `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\UserDS`. Does ist exist? Do you have permission to read it?

Comment: @DanielFisherlennybacon, yes, the registry still exists and I do have permission to read it. To that end, I know I cut it off in the screenshot, but I also was running these scripts as an Administrator in an elevated PowerShell session.

Comment: Try `Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\CurrentUser\UserDS' -Name`. If it not fails, try `Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\CurrentUser\UserDS' -Name | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "$($_.Name)" ; try { Get-Item -Path "Cert:\CurrentUser\UserDS\$($_)" -ErrorAction Stop } catch { Write-Host "^Problem here!" -f Yellow } }`. You will get a thumprint of certificate causing problem. Then you can look it closer at certmgr.msc or look at system events using ProcMon while getting `cert:\CurrentUser\UserDS\<THUMBPRINT>`

Comment: Another SO mentioning exceptions in UserDS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116450/get-all-certificates-installed-on-local-machine

Answer (score 3):

The `UserDS` store (or `Active Directory User Object` in the `certmgr.msc`) displays active directory stored certificates of the user (see [here](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/get-ad-user-object-cert-in-remote-session/), [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e51bbfa7-2cb7-4444-9f12-036b9ef9b457/certmgr-columns), [here](https://github.com/nsacyber/Windows-Secure-Host-Baseline/blob/master/Certificates/Scripts/Certificates.psm1) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/33445ceb-d779-4ea1-bd0c-36ce5c92cc1d/how-to-send-digitally-sign-smime-messages-with-powershell-cmdlet-sendmailmessage)).

The error `0x80070037` (`the specified network resource or device is no longer available`) message occurs when a local device (like an [usb stick is unavailable](https://mywindowshub.com/windows-10-error-0x80070037-the-specified-network-resource-or-device-is-no-longer-available/)) or a [network connection is interrupted](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/specified-network-resource-or-device-is-no-longer/2d6442bb-4706-465f-8101-0a65e0d937ec) while accessing a resource.

The store has a key in the windows registry (`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\UserDS`) and saves information on certificates which are **read from active director**.

I see two options:

- The information in the registry is corrupt
- you have issues accessing the active directory

If you want to handle the error when calling `Get-ChildItem` look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888149/powershell-get-childitem-how-to-catch-exception)